# Kubernetes with multus, and macvlan selecting the wrong interface eth0

Tags: kubernetes, cni, macvlan

I am working through some training on kubernetes and have the following config.
4 vm's running ubuntu 20.04 with the, one master and 3 nodes with calico CNI.
I managed to deploy some nginx pods and got the connectivity to work as expected/

I am trying to use multus to add a macvlan and have been following the instructions here
https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

The server output for ip ad on the master shows (nodes show just the first 3 interfaces)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:de:3a:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.230/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fede:3ae5/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
inet 172.16.255.128/32 scope global tunl0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: calif1302e6e8bf@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-93b9a0fa-78e3-34fa-f5e4-75b8c8b9f760
inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: cali8475067f6cf@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-255cc6e9-b83e-ed27-8487-9b957f83520d
inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: cali2b9e0768962@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-0826376f-5aea-ae7e-f10f-ae5aa6d0363a
inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

the output of kubectl describe network-attachment-definitions macvlan-conf

```
Name:         macvlan-conf
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
Kind:         NetworkAttachmentDefinition
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-10-21T00:35:01Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:config:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-10-21T00:35:01Z
  Resource Version:  491066
  UID:               a3d7f621-4ded-4987-ac65-250904528414
Spec:
  Config:  { "cniVersion": "0.3.0", "type": "macvlan", "master": "enp1s0", "mode": "bridge", "ipam": { "type": "host-local", "subnet": "192.168.100.0/24", "rangeStart": "192.168.100.200", "rangeEnd": "192.168.100.216", "routes": [ { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" } ], "gateway": "192.168.1.254" } }
Events:    <none>
```

and from kubectl describe daemonsets.apps -n kube-system kube-multus-ds

```
Name:           kube-multus-ds
Selector:       name=multus
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         app=multus
                name=multus
                tier=node
Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 1
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 4
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 4
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 4
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 4
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  4 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=multus
                    name=multus
                    tier=node
  Service Account:  multus
  Init Containers:
   install-multus-binary:
    Image:      ghcr.io/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni:snapshot-thick
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      cp
      /usr/src/multus-cni/bin/multus-shim
      /host/opt/cni/bin/multus-shim
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
      memory:     15Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /host/opt/cni/bin from cnibin (rw)
  Containers:
   kube-multus:
    Image:      ghcr.io/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni:snapshot-thick
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /usr/src/multus-cni/bin/multus-daemon
    Args:
      -cni-version=0.3.1
      -cni-config-dir=/host/etc/cni/net.d
      -multus-autoconfig-dir=/host/etc/cni/net.d
      -multus-log-to-stderr=true
      -multus-log-level=verbose
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     50Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/cni/net.d/multus.d from multus-daemon-config (ro)
      /host/etc/cni/net.d from cni (rw)
      /host/run from host-run (rw)
      /hostroot from hostroot (rw)
      /run/k8s.cni.cncf.io from host-run-k8s-cni-cncf-io (rw)
      /run/netns from host-run-netns (rw)
      /var/lib/cni/multus from host-var-lib-cni-multus (rw)
      /var/lib/kubelet from host-var-lib-kubelet (rw)
  Volumes:
   cni:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/cni/net.d
    HostPathType:  
   cnibin:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/cni/bin
    HostPathType:  
   hostroot:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /
    HostPathType:  
   multus-daemon-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      multus-daemon-config
    Optional:  false
   host-run:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run
    HostPathType:  
   host-var-lib-cni-multus:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/cni/multus
    HostPathType:  
   host-var-lib-kubelet:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/kubelet
    HostPathType:  
   host-run-k8s-cni-cncf-io:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run/k8s.cni.cncf.io
    HostPathType:  
   host-run-netns:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run/netns/
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

When I create the samplepod from the instructions it remains in
default  samplepod       0/1     ContainerCreating   0              40m

A describe show the the following

```
 Normal   AddedInterface          31m                  multus   Add eth0 [172.16.169.153/32] from k8s-pod-network
  Normal   AddedInterface          78s (x269 over 40m)  multus   (combined from similar events): Add eth0 [172.16.169.177/32] from k8s-pod-network
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  73s (x278 over 40m)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "0eb93b24a13b6330323d061f818e15b0086707d1a853a9b4df823a52e31ab059": CNI request failed with status 400: '&{ContainerID:0eb93b24a13b6330323d061f818e15b0086707d1a853a9b4df823a52e31ab059 Netns:/var/run/netns/cni-308cd3e6-f3e7-3eaf-0f25-b90dd50c3b08 IfName:eth0 Args:IgnoreUnknown=1;K8S_POD_NAMESPACE=default;K8S_POD_NAME=samplepod;K8S_POD_INFRA_CONTAINER_ID=0eb93b24a13b6330323d061f818e15b0086707d1a853a9b4df823a52e31ab059;K8S_POD_UID=53c586ce-0fd1-4991-bbff-188bb534d728 Path: StdinData:[123 34
```

There are references to eth0 in this log, but I have not specified eth0 in any of this config.

Am I missing something (quite likely)

Here is the samplepod output before the error showing the config

```
Name:             samplepod
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             kube-node-2/192.168.1.232
Start Time:       Fri, 21 Oct 2022 13:40:12 +1300
Labels:           <none>
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: cfe4778b5963e7d28365b6012ed0297a0d3c0dc9b0609c0f65a8d97f32ec7f41
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 
                  k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: macvlan-conf
Status:           Pending
IP:               
IPs:              <none>
Containers:
  samplepod:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         alpine
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/ash
      -c
      trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-htggc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-htggc:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the config from the official `multus-cni` repo - https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/blob/master/examples/macvlan-pod.yml

Specifically focusing on the `plugins` part, i.e.:

```yaml
spec:
  config: |
    {
      "name": "macvlan-conf",
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
          "type": "macvlan",
          "master": "enp1s0",
          "mode": "bridge",
          "ipam": {
            "type": "host-local",
            "subnet": "192.168.100.0/24",
            "rangeStart": "192.168.100.200",
            "rangeEnd": "192.168.100.216", 
            "routes": [
              {
                "dst": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "gw": "192.168.100.254"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

The above is not a tested example BTW.

After making the change, do all the normal jazz, such as restarting the `multus` daemonset and deleting your pod.

Comment: Same result still with the reference to eth0 in the error logs.

the definition i used was similar. Key difference was how the gateway was defined

      "rangeEnd": "192.168.100.216",
        "routes": [
          { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "gateway": "192.168.1.254"
      }

Comment: Tried removing the macvlan-conf annotation and the container starts up OK, and the eth0 exists.I assume that is being created by calico, so suspect that part was always succeeding and failing when it moved onto the macvlan creation.
Will see if any clues in the multus logs

Comment: Actually just realised that the error had changed. Seems related to the gateway changes, and saw that my gateway was in the 192.168.1.X whereas the IP range was in the 192.168.100.x. changed the gateway to 192.168.100.254 and it started Ok, with the default interface and the macvlan one.

Unsure at this point what determines what this should be. Does this field actually define the gateway. Still new to all this networking.

Comment: Apologies for the `gateway` mistake in my answer. Will fix to be `100`. Is the `Pod` now starting? Or is it still `ContainerCreating `?

Comment: No starting Ok now and both default and macvlan addresses are showing. I think the original one i found on the web had the format in this area wrong, the when I used yours I didn't pickup the 1/100, but it put me on the right track, thanks